# Update mysql database with array condition

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I have an array of unique Ids like the following one:

```
const myIds = [2, 3, 4];
```

I also have a database like this one:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | seen |
+-----+------+
|   0 |    0 |
|   1 |    0 |
|   2 |    0 |
|   3 |    0 |
|   4 |    0 |
+------------+
```

I would like to update my database so that the `seen` column of all the ids in my array are set to 1. That would leave me with this:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | seen |
+-----+------+
|   0 |    0 |
|   1 |    0 |
|   2 |    1 |
|   3 |    1 |
|   4 |    1 |
+------------+
```

I have tried this code but it only updates one entry:

```
    db.query('UPDATE table SET seen = 1 WHERE id = ?', myIds,
    function (error, results) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("ok");
    });
```

Is there any other way to do so ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @cdaiga I managed to make it work:

```
db.query('UPDATE table SET seen = 1 WHERE id IN (?)', [myIds],
    function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.query('UPDATE `table` SET seen = 1 WHERE id IN (?)', [myIds.join()],
    function (error, results) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("ok");
    }
);
```

Comment: I am having this error: `Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2,3,4'`